# Reading File, Segregating and Tesseract.js Performance

Tags: javascript, ocr, tesseract, fs

#### I'm trying to read a file whose content is a bunch of Multiple Choice Questions jot down together like below:

> SCHOOL NAME NAME OF EXAMINATION sto-vit TIME ;2 HOURS MAXIMUM MARKS 50
>   LFill in the blanks Marks -15 1 =0 2 (D157 39k IL True of false Marks
>   -5 1. Integers are closed under subtraction 2. Difference of two negative integers cannot be a positive integer. IIL. Evaluate using
>   distributivity property:- Marks - 10 1. -39x99 2. 8543+ 43x-15
>   3.53%9--109x53 4. 6817+ 683 IV. Solve the problems:- Marks - 10 1. A vehicle covers a distance of 43.2 km in 2.4 litre of petrol. How much
>   distance will it cover in 1 litre of petrol? V. Evaluate:- Marks - 10
>   11005105 2. 10101 %001

I have got this by reading an image (a question paper) with the help of Tesseract.js.

1. First of all, some of the mathematical digits including decimal points are omitted. Can I improve the performance?
2. Is there a way to identify the questions with their options separately so that it can be stored in a database for people to answer?

The object can be of this format:

```
{
  [
    q: 'Which website is this?',
    options: ['Github', 'Stackoverflow', 'Google']
  ], 
  [
   ...
  ]
}
```